# Ползунок треугольником JQuery CSS

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой. Не могу сделать прогресбар треугольной формы как на картинке. Может кто-то сталкивался с похожим?[image: вот как должно выглядеть]

Comment: автор, скажи откуда задание, интерес берет уже далеко не первый дубликат здесь

Comment: на самом деле эта задача слишком обширна для формата SO, вам нужно самому попытаться разбить её на составные части и решать уже их, а затем можно будет задать более конкретный вопрос по проблеме, с который вы столкнётесь

Comment: Это часть тестового задание для csssr.

Comment: @ Alex78191 прям массовость какая-то, задание то простое, а кандидаты то даже не пытаются свой пример кода выложить, просят готового решения(

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
}

.tt {
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="tt"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как сюда инпут рендж всунуть?

Comment: input range, тут будет не кстати...  лучше сам сделай свой ваниант